# Regex remove carriage return from end of lines if it exists

Tags: regex

The data looks like this:

```
0.43,0.57,0.71,0.29,0.71,1.00,0.57,1.00\r
0.43,0.57,0.71,0.29,0.71,1.00,0.57,1.00
0.43,0.57,0.71,0.29,0.71,1.00,0.57,1.00\r
```

and I want to extract the carriage return characters (marked with `\r` in the sample above). I have been trying this using `gm` and a capture group:

```
(.*)(?:\\r)$
```

but this matches only the lines with an `\r`. I thought the solution would be to add a `?` before the `$` but this does not work.

demo: https://regex101.com/r/jArLdS/1

Cheers

Comment: Do you want to capture all *lines* excluding `\r` - carriage return -
 at the end? Use `[^\r\n]+`. Your sample string above contains a backslash + the letter `r`. Else, use [`/(.+?)(?:\\r)?$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/8nQEqg/1).

Comment: Are those meant to be *literal* `\r`, or a carriage return char? Do you just want to match everything up to the `\r`, or do you really need to capture everything *except* `\r` *and the `\r` separately?

Comment: @Bohemian sorry for being unclear. When I wrote this question I was interpreting the \r as a two character string but it turns out to be the carriage return character - which makes the solution trivial as is pointed out above. Really I was more interested in the other case which he has also solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match all lines excluding `\r` - a *carriage return* - use

```
[^\r\n]+
```

that is a *negated character class* (`[^...]`) that matches one or more (due to `+` quantifier) characters other than `\r` and `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Portable solution.

`(^.*?)(\\r)(\r\n|\n)`

That's 3 capture groups, left-to-right, starting at `1`, not `0`.

Replace your string with capture groups 1 and 3, skipping 2.

Capture groups usually syntactically like `\1` or `$1` for most languages that use them.

Answer (score 0):

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/5sl4zB/1)

Try this regex:

```
^([^\\r\n]*)(:?\\r)?$
```

This is assuming you mean excluding the `\r` and not extracting `\r` because your original regex does that.